# File won't upload to the server using PHP upload

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm trying to get file uploads working on my inventory system but can't seem to get it working. I am using Lite Uploader and PHP.

Here is my upload.php file:

```
<?php
require('../../includes/config.php');

$urls = array();

if (isset($_POST['liteUploader_id']) && $_POST['liteUploader_id'] == 'fileUpload1'){

foreach ($_FILES['fileUpload1']['error'] as $key => $error){
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        $uploadedUrl = $var['site_url'].'assets/images/uploads/' . $_FILES['fileUpload1']['name'][$key];
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileUpload1']['tmp_name'][$key], $uploadedUrl);
        $urls[] = $uploadedUrl;
    }
}

if(file_exists($uploadedUrl)){
    $message = "Successfully uploaded file.";
} else {
    $message = "File did not upload properly.";
}

}

echo json_encode(
array(
    'message' => $message,
    'urls' => $urls,
)
);
exit;

?>
```

It appears that the file is not being moved once temporarily uploaded as there is no image shown on chrome when uploaded.

If you need any other files let me know. Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Here is the upload form code:

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload1" id="fileUpload1" class="fileUpload" />
<div id="details"></div>
<div id="response"></div>
<div id="previews"></div>
```

The form is done through javascript with the following code:

```
jQuery('.fileUpload').liteUploader({
    script: 'libraries/lite_uploader/upload.php',
    allowedFileTypes: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',
    maxSizeInBytes: 250000,
    customParams: {
        'custom': 'tester'
    },
    before: function (files)
    {
        jQuery('#details, #previews').empty();
        jQuery('#response').html('Uploading ' + files.length + ' file(s)...');
    },
    each: function (file, errors)
    {
        var i, errorsDisp = '';

        if (errors.length > 0)
        {
            jQuery('#response').html('One or more files did not pass validation');

            jQuery.each(errors, function(i, error)
            {
                errorsDisp += '<br /><span class="error">' + error.type + ' error - Rule: ' + error.rule + '</span>';
            });
        }

        jQuery('#details').append('<p>name: ' + file.name + ', type: ' + file.type + ', size:' + file.size + errorsDisp + '</p>');
    },
    success: function (response)
    {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        jQuery.each(response.urls, function(i, url)
        {
            jQuery('#previews').append(jQuery('<img>', {'src': url, 'width': 200}));
        });

        jQuery('#response').html(response.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add your form code here?

Comment: Did you check the return value of `move_uploaded_file()`? It's boolean FALSE on failure. Your code is also a HIDEOUS security vulnerability. You do not do **ANY** Kind of validation on the upload files and are blindly using the user-provided filenames. A malicious user can embed pathing information in that name and your script will happily scribble that file **ANYWHERE** on your server that the user wants.

Comment: Hi, I've just edited the question for you guys. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Verify that the destination folder is writable.  Turn on error reporting and check your logs.